# How to scroll content automatically using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am a CSS beginner. I want to scroll the names of developers on the credits section of my website using only CSS. Like this website [wrangle.in](http://www.wrangle.in). But they used javascript and jquery, but I want pure CSS solution but output as same as the website. Any tutorial link will be useful.

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: what makes you believe that pure CSS can achieve this result?

Comment: because css has an animation property..so I thought it might achieve this.

Comment: @JuliaTheAngel: Yeah, it might be possible with CSS3, however that is quite advanced. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: thanks @Bergi I will try out that tutorial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this, here's a simple example I knocked together:

```
<div id='container'>
<ul id='credits'>
    <li>Tom Doug</li>
    <li>Sophia</li>
    <li>Emma</li>
    <li>Olivia</li>
    <li>Isabella</li>
    <li>Ava</li>
    <li>Lily</li>
    <li>Zoe</li>
    <li>Chloe</li>
    <li>Mia</li>
    <li>Madison</li>
    <li>Emily</li>
    <li>Ella</li>
    <li>Madelyn</li>
    <li>Abigail</li>
    <li>Aubrey</li>
    <li>Addison</li>
    <li>Avery</li>
    <li>Layla</li>
</ul>
```

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#credits {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: goup 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: goup 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes goup {
    from { top: 0px; }
    to { top: -400px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes goup {
    from { top: 0px; }
    to { top: -400px; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rJ6t/2/

beware the differences between browsers, CSS3 animation is fairly new stuff.